# Eloquent join returns empty data set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to join 3 tables, are  - customer, customer_item and items.

- customer - customer details
- items - item details
- customer_item - relation between customer and items

Customer - model

```
public function itemRel(){
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerItem::class,'customer_id');
}
```

CustomerItem - model

```
public function itemDetails(){  
    return $this->hasOne(Items::class, 'id');
}
```

CustomerController

```
$customer = Customers::find($id);
$data = $customer->itemRel();
return $data;
```

Schema structure

```
customer - [id,name,mobile,username...]
items - [id, item_name, quantity, nature ....]
customer_item - [id, customer_id,item_id...]
```

I want to list all the items that related to the user (customer_item)

Comment: What data you want to get in the data result? Do you want to get all products associated with a particular customer(buyer)?

Comment: I want to list all the items that related to current / logged in user @MihirBhende

Comment: It would help if you could give us the table schema structure.

Comment: @Ekown please check the structure now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `belongsToMany` relation instead

**Customer - model**

```
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Items::class,'customer_item','customer_id','item_id');
}
```

**Items - model**

```
public function customers(){    
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class,'customer_item','item_id','customer_id');
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
$customer = Customers::find($id);
$data = $customer->items();
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your model code like:

**Customer** - model

```
public function itemRel(){
    return $this->belongsTo(CustomerItem::class,'customer_id');
}
```

**CustomerItem** - model

```
public function customer(){  
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

**Updated Answer**

**Customer** - model

```
public function itemRel(){
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerItem::class);
}
```

***CustomerItem*** - model

```
public function customer(){  
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
}
```

Comment: Missed `belongsTo` now returns empty set

Comment: Please check in question @AddWeb

Comment: Customers::with('itemRel')->with('customer')->find($id) returning error

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$customer = Customers::with('itemRel')->find($id);
$data = $customer->itemRel;
return $data;
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: returning data now, how to get details of the items

Comment: please tell me the relationship between the models.

Comment: I think you want this:........... $customer = Customers::with('itemRel')->with('itemDetails')->find($id);

Comment: I got the detail of the item but only one. And do i need to define itemRel as well itemDetails in Customer model itself ?

Comment: Yes you need to define itemRel, itemDetails in Customer model. You can follow the official documentation of [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Use it without parenthesis

```
$data = $customer->itemRel;
```

to get actual model data use

```
$data->propertyName
```